# How do I open google search results in different tabs with code?

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

I want to get the top Google search results using one of Google's API.  Then I want to take the results or the result urls and do with them as I please... say open each result in a new tab or add some code so that I can retrieve information from each site (maybe down load the various pages that turned up in my search results).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new XMLHttpRequest or something similar. To fetch data from e.g. the

google search Api. *`'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='+q+'&callback=?'`*

*It's being replaced by the Google Custom Search, but it should be manageable to figure out how to use it instead of the search api with a bit of googling and [googles article](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started)  on getting started*

You then can access the results in the `responseData`'s `result` property *an Array with the result*

Those hold various properties like the `title` or a `content` description.

```
$.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=stackoverflow&callback=?', function(e) {
  var links = e.responseData.results;
  /* Do something with the Data */
});
```

You get an Array with the search Results.
Take the data you need and feel free to use/manipulate or open them in new Windows/Tabs. Whatever you want.

Here is an Example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ozemip/1/edit), which searches for Stackoverflow and Provides you with a link to the first result

Comment: thanks! I appreciate your help.  I've got the array and turned the results into variables.  Now for the fun.  thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome =) It's a pleasure i could help you =) Thats how I learn and am able to improve my knowledge, so thanks to you as well =)